# Using regex to set a specific digit to NA?

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub, stringr

Sample of df:

```
   LASSO_deviance LASSO_AUC
68          0.999     0.999
2           1.000     1.000
39          1.000     1.005
7            1.02       1.2
```

I want to set cells which contain `1.000` to either `NA` or `0`, in preferential order.

I've tried something like: `df %>% mutate_at(vars(LASSO_deviance, LASSO_AUC), funs(gsub(pattern = "1{1}[^.{1,}]", 0, x = .)))` with no luck.

Comment: `df[df == 1] <- NA` ?

Comment: Do your columns contain text or actual numerical data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen numeric, but I've tried setting the cols to text but both don't work.

Comment: Read the very first comment.

Comment: `1.000 to either NA or 0` **WHAT DO YOU WANT?** Replace `1 -> NA` or `1 -> 0`.

Comment: btw: avoid using regex when you're working with numeric-only input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tt <- "LASSO_deviance LASSO_AUC
68          0.999     0.999
2           1.000     1.000
39          1.000     1.005
7            1.02       1.2"

dat <- read.table(text = tt, header = T)
```

No need for regex because you can simply find where your data is equal to 1.000

```
dat[dat == 1.000] <- NA # or dat[dat == 1.000] <- 0
dat

# LASSO_deviance LASSO_AUC
# 68          0.999     0.999
# 2              NA        NA
# 39             NA     1.005
# 7           1.020     1.200
```